# pymodbus RTU communication

Tags: python, pymodbus

Implemented below code to communicate python program with Modbus RTU protocol. However trying to read/write data to/from the python program, ModPoll software throws first timeout error & then "Insufficient byte received"

**Kindly request to suggest the correct code to communicate with ModPoll.**

```
enter code here

from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
client = ModbusSerialClient(method="rtu", port="COM1", stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=9600, timeout=200)
print(client.connect())
# result = client.read_holding_registers(102, 1, unit=1)
# print(result.registers)
client.write_register(1, 45, unit=1)
client.write_register(2, 45, unit=1)
client.write_register(3, 45, unit=1)
client.write_register(4, 45, unit=1)
client.write_register(5, 45, unit=1)
```